# How to set mutipule inAppBrowser options

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to set both hidden and location to 'no' When I try individually it works.

In the following it doesn't. pls help.

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no&hidden=no');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to separate the options by a comma. From the Phonegap [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser): 
"The options string must not contain any blank space, and each feature's name/value pairs must be separated by a comma. Feature names are case insensitive."
So you would want something like:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=no');
```